# Unknown error when upgrading from SSRS 2014 to 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2017

I had to upgrade the report server used by some application from SSRS 2014 to SSRS 2016.

I did the migration manually, because the old and new SSRS were installed on  different machines, and I could not do an in-place update.

So the approach was (long story short):

- backup ReportServer on SSRS 2014
- install SSRS 2016 on new server
- restore ReportServer database
- update its structure to match SSRS 2016; I used Sql Compare to get structure from an in-purpose, empty ReportServer database created by SSRS 2016
- added record in **ServerUpgradeHistory** with version for SSRS 2016 (173)
- restored the Encryption keys from SSRS 2014.

Everything works ok, with one small issue.

When I try to open SSRS Web Portal URL (http://...myServer.../Reports), or to refresh main page, I get the following error popup.

[image: Error popup when loading or refreshing Web Portal URL]

This error doesn't appear to affect the functionality of SSRS - all reports work just fine. Also it does's appear when opening Web Service URL (http://...myServer.../ReportServer).

So it's just annoying so far.

I searched for the guid string in Catalog table (I thought it might be some folder name or something), but I found nothing.

Does anyone have any idea where it comes from and how to get rid of it?

Thank you

---

**Edit**

Recently I updated from SSRS 2016 to 2017, and I kept carrying this error with me.
However I found the offending item. It is in Catalog table, and it is of Type = 3 (Resource), with mime-type application/octet-stream

I deleted it from catalog (I did a backup of it into a separate table - catalog_bak), but I still get the error when I load main page in (/reports)

Beside that, it never pops-up again, with one exception: it always shows-up when I access Site Settings -> Branding

I guess it has something to do with branding packages.
Does anyone knows where are they stored, and how can I uninstall /  clean-up that?

[image: Error when accessing Branding section in Site Setings]

Comment: I assume that one of your reports has a reference to this item. Since SSRS cannot find it in the catalog throws the error. Check the item existance in your original server database to see what it is.

Comment: Check ReportServer.dbo.Keys You may have a reference to the old server in there.

Comment: @alan, I checked the Keys table, and there is no such item.

Comment: @niktrs - what tables should I check this item in? Basically, since I transferred the db backup, everything that was in db on old server should be in db on new server. Any other idea? Thank you both for advice

Comment: I would compare the 2 catalog tables and verify that nothing is missing `SELECT * FROM OLDSERVER.ReportSeverDB.dbo.Catalog WHERE NOT EXISTS (...NEWSERVER.ReportServerDB.dbo.Catalog...)`

Answer (score 0):

A Branding Package is created by a user. If the original package can't be found or is corrupted it should revert to the default. Have you tried removing the package or creating and uploading a new one?  Also, try downloading SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50400) and then connect your server with it. It may contain a theme that was used on your original server.

Answer (score 0):

For me Uninstall and Reinstall did the trick for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).